# Concatenating Dataframe Inside Loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I am querying an API that lets you request n# of items in a single API call. So I am breaking up the list of items I am querying into n# of "sublists", passing them to a function which returns the API data, and then concatenating the data to a Dataframe.

But when I loop through the "sublists", the final Dataframe only contains the last "sublist", rather than every "sublist". So instead of:

```
       netIncome sharesOutstanding
BRK.B         20                40
V             50                60
MSFT          30                10
ORCL          12                24
AMZN          33                55
GOOGL         66                88
```

I get:

```
       netIncome sharesOutstanding
AMZN          33                55
GOOGL         66                88
```

Here is the full code, so can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
import os
from iexfinance.stocks import Stock
import pandas as pd

# Set IEX Finance API Token (Public Sandbox Version)
os.environ['IEX_API_VERSION'] = 'iexcloud-sandbox'
os.environ['IEX_TOKEN'] = 'XXXXXX'

def fetch_company_info(group):
    """Function to query API data"""
    batch = Stock(group, output_format='pandas')

    # Get income from last 4 quarters, sum it, and store to temp Dataframe
    df_income = batch.get_income_statement(period="quarter", last='4')
    df_income = df_income.T.sum(level=0)
    income_ttm = df_income.loc[:, ['netIncome']]

    # Get number of shares, and store to temp Dataframe
    df_shares = batch.get_key_stats(period="quarter")
    shares_outstanding = df_shares.loc['sharesOutstanding']

    return income_ttm, shares_outstanding

# Full list to query via API
tickers = ['BRK.B', 'V', 'MSFT', 'ORCL', 'AMZN', 'GOOGL']

# Chunk ticker list into n# of lists
n = 2
batch_tickers = [tickers[i * n:(i + 1) * n] for i in range((len(tickers) + n - 1) // n)]

# Loop through each chunk of tickers
for group in batch_tickers:
    company_info = fetch_company_info(group)
    output_df = pd.concat(company_info, axis=1, sort='true')

print(output_df)
```

Comment: Are you sure you understand how concat works? If you concatenate `company_info` with nothing in every loop, your dataframe will only contain the results from the last loop. You should start with an empty DataFrame and then **append**

Comment: I thought best practice was to avoid **append** because it's inefficient. Since the real ```ticker``` list is going to contain thousands of items, I'd like to make it as performant as possible.

Comment: You're right. So Lauzloo's solution should work!

Comment: You return 2 dataframes and store it in one variable `company_info`. How's that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do another `pd.concat`. The first one concats the the `income_ttm` and `shares_outstanding` column but you then need to use `pd.concat` in the row direction to add new rows to `output_df`.

First create `output_df`, where its first row is the first sublist. Then concat each new sublist to `output_df`. Also, it should be `axis=0` instead of `axis=1` because you want to concatenate in row direction, not column direction.

Try something like this at the end of your code:

```py
# Loop through each chunk of tickers
for i in range(len(batch_tickers)):
    group = batch_tickers[i]
    company_info = fetch_company_info(group)
    ## concat income and shares outstanding
    company_df = pd.concat(company_info, axis=1, sort='true')
    # instantiate output_df to be company_info with first row
    if(i==0):
        output_df = company_df
    # for other rows, concat company_df
    else:
        output_df = pd.concat([output_df, company_df], axis=0)
```

Comment: I get ```TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type "<class 'tuple'>"; only pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel (deprecated) objs are valid```

Comment: Try again. Just edited post. Should be `pd.concat([output_df, company_df], axis=0)` not `pd.concat([output_df, company_info], axis=0)`

Answer (score 1):

Try List Comprehension first and concatenate afterward

```
company_info = [fetch_company_info(group) for group in batch_tickers]

output_df = pd.concat(company_info, axis=1, sort='true')
```

Comment: I get ```TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type "<class 'tuple'>"; only pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel (deprecated) objs are valid```

Comment: What does the `fetch_company_info()` function return?

Comment: I just added the full code which might be easier. Note that you can use the token as it's meant to be public, and only returns sandbox data.

Answer (score 1):

```
def fetch_company_info(group):
    """Function to query API data"""
    batch = Stock(group, output_format='pandas')

    # Get income from last 4 quarters, sum it, and store to temp Dataframe
    df_income = batch.get_income_statement(period="quarter", last='4')
    df_income = df_income.T.sum(level=0)
    income_ttm = df_income.loc[:, ['netIncome']]

    # Get number of shares, and store to temp Dataframe
    df_shares = batch.get_key_stats(period="quarter")
    shares_outstanding = df_shares.loc['sharesOutstanding']

    df = pd.concat([income_ttm, shares_outstanding], ignore_index=True, axis=1)

    return df
```

.......

```
# Loop through each chunk of tickers
dataframes= []
for group in batch_tickers:
    company_info = fetch_company_info(group)
    dataframes.append(company_info )

df = reduce(lambda top, bottom: pd.concat([top, bottom], sort=False), dataframes)
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without **append**? I've been advised against using it with dataframes as it tends to be resource heavy.